# Valid parentheses of multiple types with given suffix

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, catalan-numbers

I have task that touches the problem around Catalan numbers. I have multiple types of parentheses (2 and 3 is enough right now) and I am given number of pairs for each parentheses. I know that with Catalan numbers I can calculate number of combinations for one with Catalan calculated through binomial coefficient $$ \frac{{2n}\choose{n}}{(n+1)}$$ for two $$ \frac{{{2n+2m}\choose{n+m}}\cdot{{n+m}\choose{n}}}{(n+m+1)} $$ etc.

But what to do if I am given a suffix?

For example I know that the combinations need to end with ")])". How many combinations I need to divide from the result?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how to derive the formula for $n$ pairs of parentheses and $m$ pairs of brackets.  First we pretend that we have $n+m$ pairs of parentheses, and calculate the number of balanced strings.  Then we choose $m$ of the pairs to be brackets.  In the example you give, one pair is already determined to be a bracket and two are determined to be parentheses, so you have to choose $m-1$ pairs out of the remaining $n+m-3$ pairs to be brackets.

That is, instead of $\binom{n+m}{m},$ the second factor needs to be $\binom{n+m-3}{m-1}.$

Comment: Okay. I understand that. If I have suffix with for example "]()" does it change a thing? I calculate with pairs therefore I have to take into account only two pairs with this suffix, right? Thank you.

Comment: I think so, if I understand you right.  This eliminates one pair of parentheses and one pair of brackets, so the second factor is $\binom{n+m-2}{m-1}$